# How to tweak Default User Settings of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-code

I want to set the operating system environment variables ‘http_proxy’ and ‘https_proxy’ as instructed from the [VSCode Setup site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/setup-overview#_proxy-server-support). 
The default settings is located at  File > Preferences > User Settings or Code > Preferences > User Settings. 
 To make the changes in default settings `settings.json` opens at side of the default settings, which displays:

```
//Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
enter code here
}
```

I added following within the curly braces and saved the file:

```
{
    "http.proxy": "http://10.203.0.1:5187/", 
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false
}
```

Yet the default settings is not edited. 
How to make changes in Default Settings?

Comment: Why do you want to edit Default Settings? If you need to modify some setting or add a new one, you need to edit User Settings. Those override Default ones. Default will always remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the "default settings". They are the defaults. The settings that you've changed, either User or Workspace settings, will always live in their own files and won't change the "default settings" file. vscode opens the default file next to your custom settings file so that you can see all the settings that are available and the default value they are set to.

If you are concerned that the settings you are changing aren't working, though, add this line to your settings and save it and you should see the font change instantly:

`"editor.fontFamily": "Papyrus"`

You'll notice the font change, but the default will stay the same. But if you set it in "user settings", that setting will now be setting every time you use chrome. If you only want it to apply to a particular project, use workspace settings.

Bonus: If you want the settings to follow you across multiple machines, you can use an extension like [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync).